# Github no actualiza cambios

Tags: git, github, git-push

Recién hoy me di cuenta que mi repositorio no se está actualizando desde el día 3 de Marzo (estamos a 21)

El procedimiento es el de siempre

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "comentarios"
git push origin staging
```

Sin embargo en mi local aparece que los cambios fueron aplicados:
lmancuso@LB-140:~/Downloads/anose$ git push origin staging
Everything up-to-date

No se por donde empezar.. busqué por Internet y no logro dar con la solución.

Comment: `staging` es la rama cierto? Cómo te diste cuenta de que no se está actualizando? Estás seguro de que estás mirando en la rama correcta?

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron, lo más probable es que estés mirando la rama **master**, en lugar la **staging**. Puesdes cambiar de rama en el siguiente desplegable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]